# How can I integrate Open Office (32-bit) with a 64-bit Java Runtime Environment?

Tags: java, coldfusion, openoffice.org

I am currently running a ColdFusion 11 64-bit installation with Java JRE 1.8.66 64-bit on Windows 2012. I want to install Open Office along with the JODConverter Java library so that I can use the libraries to convert Office files to PDFs with code. I have successfully run this installation in Windows 2003 32-bit with ColdFusion 8 32-bit. I also have this successfully working in Windows 7 with ColdFusion 8 and 64-bit JRE.

On the CF11/2012 server, I have installed Open Office 3.4.1, but it only allows a 32-bit installation. I'm thinking the 32-bit/64-bit differences is causing a problem because every time I try to instantiate the Java library, it throws an "Object instantiation exception":

Stack trace:

```
Message: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration
    StackTrace: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:235)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory$1.run(JavaProxyFactory.java:156)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory.getProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:151)
        at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:6167)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6130)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6064)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6039)
        at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5986)
```

Is there any way to get this integration to work correctly?

Comment: Did you see this documentation on Configuring OpenOffice with ColdFusion 11? [Installing Integrated Technologies](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing/installing-integrated-technologies.html) _there is a Configuring OpenOffice section at the bottom_  Look at the JAR files that they are including in the class path and library path for Windows servers. If that still does not get you passed the instantiate issue then it looks like they also have an option for running the OpenOffice remotely if it truly is a bitness issue (also mentioned in the linked document).

Comment: You cannot mix and match 32-bit and 64-bit Java on Windows; the WoW64 subsystem cannot interface with WoW32.

Comment: @Miguel-F, yes, I read that, but, it didn't really tell me anything I didn't already know. I'm thinking I need to re-install ColdFusion as 32-bit at this point. Didn't know if there was some trick to make it work.

Comment: You can install 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs on the same Windows desktop, so long as they're installed to different folders. Why wouldn't that be the case for Windows 2012? Have you tried? If you can, it should just be a matter of configuring Open Office to point to the 32-bit JVM.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno yes, I'm aware, and tried that, but, I'm running ColdFusion on top of Java, and the ColdFusion installation is 64-bit.

Comment: You could try the 64-bit version of LibreOffice 5 to see if it is stable enough yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the best solution is to replace my existing code - which invokes the JODConverter java libraries - with **CFDOCUMENT** calls, since the Java objects are no longer needed for the needed functionality in ColdFusion 11.